# ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number error using SP

Tags: mysql, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I am using `SP` to insert data into my table.

Below is my SP

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE XXCUS.pn_insert_grid_agreeement (
        mkey             NUMBER,
        stattype         VARCHAR2,
        ref_no           NUMBER,
        ref_date         DATE,
        STAT_712         varchar2,  
        trantype         VARCHAR2,
        createdby        NUMBER,
        creationdate     DATE,
        lastupdatedate   DATE,
        lastupdatedby    NUMBER,
        deleteflag       CHAR
    )
    IS
    BEGIN
   INSERT INTO xxcus.xxacl_pn_agrmt_grd
           (mkey, stat_type, ref_no, ref_date, stat_7_12, tran_type,
            created_by, creation_date, last_update_date,
            last_updated_by, delete_flag
           )
    VALUES (mkey, stattype, ref_no, ref_date, STAT_712, trantype, createdby,
            creationdate, lastupdatedate, lastupdatedby,
            deleteflag
           );
    END;
```

I want to insert data into my `xxcus.xxacl_pn_agrmt_grd` table. So in my code behind I have written like this

```
OracleConnection ObjPriCon = new OracleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ToString());
    ObjPriCon.Open();
    string strQuery = "XXCUS.pn_insert_grid_agreeement";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(strQuery, ObjPriCon);

    string mkey = "1";

    cmd.Parameters.Add("mkey", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(mkey);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("stattype", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["STAT_TYPE"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ref_no", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Record["ref_no"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("ref_date", OracleType.DateTime).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Record["ref_date"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("STAT_712", OracleType.VarChar).Value = e.Record["stat_7_12"];
    cmd.Parameters.Add("trantype", OracleType.VarChar).Value = "AD";
    cmd.Parameters.Add("createdby", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("creationdate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lastupdatedate", OracleType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("lastupdatedby", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["userid"]);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("deleteflag", OracleType.Char).Value = "N";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // here is error
    ObjPriCon.Close();
```

But while saving I get error as

> ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

I have specified all the columns properly with datatype as required.

Also see my table structure.

```
CREATE TABLE XXCUS.XXACL_PN_AGRMT_GRD
        (
      MKEY              NUMBER(10)                  NOT NULL,
      USER_ID           NUMBER(10),
      STAT_TYPE         VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
      REF_NO            NUMBER(10),
      REF_DATE          DATE,
      STAT_7_12         VARCHAR2(100 BYTE),
      TRAN_TYPE         VARCHAR2(3 BYTE)            NOT NULL,
      CREATED_BY        NUMBER(10),
      CREATION_DATE     DATE,
      LAST_UPDATE_DATE  DATE,
      LAST_UPDATED_BY   NUMBER(10),
      DELETE_FLAG       CHAR(1 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE1        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE2        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE3        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE4        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE5        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE6        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE7        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE8        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE9        VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE10       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE11       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE12       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE13       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE14       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE),
      ATTRIBUTE15       VARCHAR2(255 BYTE)
    )
```

Pls let me know what is the error.

Comment: *Pls let me know what is the error* This error occurs when the parameters are not properly passed to the SQLDatasource or Command object when connecting to Oracle Database using System.Data.OracleClient.

Comment: @Div: I have passed it properly. I just added `mkey` as hardcoded as it is auto incremented. can u help me with this